# ServiceStack removes 'json' literal when part of matching route parameter

Tags: servicestack

I have a route that looks like something similar to this:

```
[Route("/servejson/{JsonId}", Verbs = "GET", Summary = "")]
```

When I hit my host with `/servejson/test.json`, I get `test.` as my JsonId parameter.  I'd like to get `test.json` as JsonId. ServiceStack seems to be removing the 'json' part of my parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is explained in the [Routing wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing#content-negotiation) where servicestack will look at the extension to see if it's a supported content type, if it is it will automatically pre-set the response content-type and trim the extension so that it's transparent in your services.

You can disable this default behavior in your AppHost.SetConfig with:

```
Config.AllowRouteContentTypeExtensions = false.
```

Comment: Thank you, fixed my ServiceStack service which was acting as our file CDN. Would not properly serve up XML files until this option was turned off.